# Unexpected exception thrown when looking up user information

Tags: c#, exception, active-directory, active-directory-group

I have some code that is looking up group memberships from local groups on a machine. For each member, it tries to load some information about the user (eg. find a group and get the names of each of its members).

The code:

```
using (DirectoryEntry machine = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName + ", Computer"))
{
    using (DirectoryEntry group = machine.Children.Find(groupName, "group"))
    {
        object members = group.Invoke("members", null);

        foreach (object groupMember in (IEnumerable) members)
        {
            using (DirectoryEntry member = new DirectoryEntry(groupMember))
            {
                member.RefreshCache();
                string name = member.Name;
                // <code snipped>
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code works fine most of the time, but for some group members, it throws a `FileNotFoundException` when the `RefreshCache()` method is thrown:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 
    The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
    (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007B)
at System.DirectoryServices.Interop.UnsafeNativeMethods.IAds.GetInfo()
at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.RefreshCache()
at GroupLookup.GetLocalGroupMembership(String groupName)
```

What is causing the `FileNotFoundException` (and what file is it looking for)?

Comment: A very short straw to clutch at, but do the group members in question have an "&" in their name?

If not, can you post some sample group member names which cause the problem?

Comment: @Neil: no they don't. The error is happening at a customer site, and I had already asked that question. They assure me that the member names only contain letters.

Comment: Are there systems for which this is working?

Comment: @Stephen: Yes. In fact, I have no systems that it fails on except the one at the customer site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get to the bottom of what was causing the `FileNotFoundException`, although I suspect it was to do with the group set-up - the groups had both local and domain users in them.

Because I only needed the users' names and SIDs, and these were already present on the `DirectoryEntry`, I solved this issue by not calling the `RefreshCache` method. This lets the code execute without an exception.

Answer (score 2):

The file-not-found error is commonly used in the Win32 API as a "resource not found" error. So, it's returned for things like missing Registry keys, or - in this case - an ADSI node.

I am definitely not an ADSI expert, but your first call to the `DirectoryEntry` constructor seems to be using an invalid path style [according to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746534(v=VS.85).aspx). I believe you'd need the domain name before the machine name.

**Update:**

Noticed this on [another MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772211(v=VS.85).aspx): "GetInfo cannot be used for groups that contain members that are wellKnown security principals in the WinNT scope."

Given the stack trace, it seems like this may be causing the problem.

Comment: The machine is part of a domain, but I am querying the local groups information (the local groups may contain domain items though). I thought that I would not need the domain name in this case.

Comment: In this case, I would try the `WinNT://<server>` path, without specifying the `computer` type.

Comment: I looked at it with fresh eyes. Check out the answer update (which is really a totally different answer), and see if that helps.